# Filling in empty dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query returns the number of alarms created by day between a specific date range.

```
SELECT CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS date, SUM(1) AS count
FROM ew_alarms
LEFT JOIN site ON site.id = ew_alarms.site_id
AND ew_alarms.created_at BETWEEN '12/22/2020' AND '01/22/2021' AND (CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ew_alarms.created_at) AS INT) BETWEEN 0 AND 23.99)
GROUP BY CAST(created_at AS DATE)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Result: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YDLY.png)

What the best way to fill in the missing dates (1/16, 1/17, 1/18, etc)? Due to no alarms created on those days these results throw off the daily average I'm ultimately trying to achieve.

Would it be a `generate_series` query?

Comment: Recursive CTE is one of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `generate_series()`.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT gs.date, COUNT(s.site_id) AS count
FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2020-12-22'::date, '2021-01-22'::date, INTERVAL '1 DAY') gs(dte) LEFT JOIN
     ew_alarms a
     ON ew.created_at >= gs.dte AND
        ew.created_at < gs.dte + INTERVAL '1 DAY' LEFT JOIN
     site s
     ON s.id = a.site_id 
GROUP BY gs.dte
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I don't know what the hour comparison is supposed to be doing.  The hour is always going to be between 0 and 23, so I removed that logic.

Note:  Presumably, you want to count something from either `site` or `ew_alarms`.  That is expected with `LEFT JOIN`s so `0` can be returned.

Comment: Had to make a few tweaks but works great. Thank you